# Unexpected Behavior of QRegularExpression

Tags: qt

I've just started switching to QRegularExpression, and I'm using it to tokenize a string with multiple delimiter possibilities. I've encountered a surprising behavior, which seems to me to be a bug. I'm using Qt 5.5.1 on Windows.

Here's sample code:

```
#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QString>
#include <QtDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Q_UNUSED (argc);
    Q_UNUSED (argv);
    QRegularExpression regex ("^ ");

    qDebug () << "Expected:    " << QString ("M 100").indexOf(regex);
    qDebug () << "NOT expected:" << QString ("M 100").indexOf(regex, 1);
    qDebug () << "Expected:    " << QString (" 100").indexOf(regex);

    QRegularExpression regex1 (" ");
    qDebug () << "Expected:    " << QString ("M 100").indexOf(regex1);
}
```

And the output:

```
Expected:     -1
NOT expected: -1
Expected:     0
Expected:     1
```

The use of the caret (^) when used with a starting position other than 0 in the "indexOf" call is preventing the expression from matching. Intuitively, I expected that the caret matches the string at the position that I specified. Instead, it simply never matches.

I'm going to switch my tokenizing to use splitRref to avoid this problem. While that's probably slightly cleaner anyway, I need to understand whether this is correct behavior or if I should be reporting a bug to Qt.

UPDATE: Using splitRef doesn't entirely solve my problem because I need to use a regular expression to detect if some tokens are floating point numbers, and I can't use a QRegularExpression with QStringRef. For that possibility, I have to convert my QStringRef token into an actual QString, which was what I was trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: Well, ^ matches the first character of the string, and offset 1 is not the first character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` matches *at the beginning of the subject string*, or *after a newline when in multiline mode*. The offset does not alter these semantics. Hence, matching `/^ /` (in regex notation) against `M 100` at offset 1 correctly results in no match.

Perhaps you want `\G`? From [`pcrepattern(3)`](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html):

> `\G`     matches at the first matching position in the subject
>
> The `\G` assertion is true only when the current matching position is at the start point of the match, as specified by the *startoffset* argument of `pcre_exec()`. It differs from `\A` when the value of *startoffset* is non-zero.

With that, this code:

```
QRegularExpression regex ("\\G ");

qDebug () << "Expected:    " << QString ("M 100").indexOf(regex);
qDebug () << "NOT expected:" << QString ("M 100").indexOf(regex, 1);
qDebug () << "Expected:    " << QString (" 100").indexOf(regex);
```

prints

```
Expected:     -1
NOT expected: 1
Expected:     0
```

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't thought about the \G assertion since I wasn't starting from a previous match position, but it makes sense. It would've been nice if this were explicitly stated in the Qt docs, but I know the behavior from Perl. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Well, it's the same in Perl: `perl -E '$_ = "M 100"; pos() = 1; say $-[0] if /\G /;'` (prints 1).

Comment: I'm saying that it's not obvious to use this even though I know it from Perl. It cost me a fair amount of time today, and since it's both an easy thing to miss, and the \G assertion isn't as commonly known as other options, it would've been nice to have that tip included in the Qt documents.

Comment: When writing the QRegularExpression document, I was somehow conflicted about what to put in there w.r.t. the supported syntax. In the end, I chose not to duplicate the enormous syntax documentation, and just refer people to the pcrepattern(3) and the perlre documentation pages.